# Ubuntu 20.04 ssh-keygen unknown option -G unable to generate Diffie-Hellman parameters

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keygen, ubuntu-20.04

I have noticed that the ssh-keygen for ubuntu 20.04 is missing the options for generating the Diffie-Hellman parameters.  This is normally part of SSH hardening.  Does anyone know why it has disappeared?

Answer (score 9):

The reason invoked was to free up several option letters for the `ssh-keygen` command. This was consolidated in additional `-O` options and an modified use of the `-M` option, which breaks compatibility with former versions. This was done on 30 Dec 2019 in [this commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/3e60d18fba1b502c21d64fc7e81d80bcd08a2092):

> upstream: remove single-letter flags for moduli options
>
> Move all moduli generation options to live under the -O flag.
>
> **Frees up seven single-letter flags**.
>
> NB. this change break existing ssh-keygen commandline syntax for
>   moduli- related operations. Very few people use these fortunately.
>
> feedback and ok markus@
>
> OpenBSD-Commit-ID: d498f3eaf28128484826a4fcb343612764927935

The newer syntax is described in the newer (focal) [`ssh-keygen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) man page under [MODULI GENERATION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html#moduli%20generation):

> Generation of primes is performed using the `-M generate` option.  The desired length of the primes may be specified by the `-O bits` option. For example:
>
> ```
> # ssh-keygen -M generate -O bits=2048 moduli-2048.candidates
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> # ssh-keygen -M screen -f moduli-2048.candidates moduli-2048
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ubuntu issue, it is actually a part of OpenSSH. the diffie-hellman algorithm is notably weak and so they have made it legacy in more recent versions in favor of stronger algorithms.

If you need to communicate with a system that requires diffie-hellman you can do:

`ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@legacyhost`

Or you can substitute any legacy algorithm in place of diffie-hellman

Comment: Using group1 is the OPPOSITE of generating your own groups, which is the question here.